# Unable to create a binary from nodejs app using pkg

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am unable to create a binary executable from nodejs app using pkg command.

I have a simple nodejs app consisting of just three .js files namely: `index.js`, `xlsx_to_pdf.js` and `xlsx_extractor.js`.

This is how my package.json looks =>

```
{
  "name": "whatsapp-order",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This package automates the process of sending orders to whatsapp contacts",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "pdfkit": "^0.13.0",
    "pdfkit-table": "^0.1.99",
    "qrcode-terminal": "^0.12.0",
    "whatsapp-web.js": "^1.18.4",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  }
}
```

The whatsapp-web.js uses puppeteer.

When I try to compile the code using command `npx pkg index.js`, I get the following warnings.

```
> pkg@5.8.0
> Targets not specified. Assuming:
  node14-linux-x64, node14-macos-x64, node14-win-x64
> Warning Cannot include directory %1 into executable.
  The directory must be distributed with executable as %2.
  The directory must be distributed with executable as %2.
  %1: node_modules\puppeteer\.local-chromium
  %2: path-to-executable/puppeteer
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node14-x64 for file /snapshot/whatsapp-order/node_modules/brotli/build/encode.js       
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node14-x64 for file /snapshot/whatsapp-order/node_modules/brotli/build/encode.js       
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node14-x64 for file C:\snapshot\whatsapp-order\node_modules\brotli\build\encode.js
```

When I try to run the generated executable in cmd using command `.\index-win.exe`, I get the following error:

```
pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1876
      throw error;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\snapshot\whatsapp-order\node_modules\es-get-iterator\node.js'
1) If you want to compile the package/file into executable, please pay attention to compilation warnings and specify a literal in 'require' call. 2) If you don't want to compile the package/file into executable and want to 'require' it from filesystem (likely plugin), specify an absolute path in 'require' call using process.cwd() or process.execPath.
    at createEsmNotFoundErr (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:929:15)
    at finalizeEsmResolution (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:922:15)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:450:14)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:490:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888:27)
    at Function._resolveFilename (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1955:46)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1855:31)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\whatsapp-order\node_modules\deep-equal\index.js:14:19)
    at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1930:22)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\snapshot\\whatsapp-order\\node_modules\\es-get-iterator\\package.json',
  pkg: true
}
```

I am quite new to this, if you can tell me where the problem is and how to fix it or suggest me an alternate way to compile nodejs app to an executable, it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure. Never did this. But i think that you should set target for what platform compile your program at

```bash
pkg -o /bin/my-program -t node14-win-x64
```

https://github.com/vercel/pkg
Also you can read this.
https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues/935